# Making a DIV hide once FancyBox is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to make an Div disappear when you click the open FancyBox button.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tag_100_not').fancybox({
        'transitionIn'        : 'elastic'  ,
        'transitionOut'       : 'elastic'  ,
        'hideOnOverlayClick'  : false      ,
        'hideOnContentClick'  : false      ,
        'showCloseButton'     : false      ,
        'overlayOpacity'      : 0.6        ,
        'onStart'             : function() {
            $('#tag_100_not').css('display', 'none');
        },

        'onComplete'          : function() {
            $('#tag_100_not').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

MarkUp:

```
    <th class="num" style="position:relative;"><a id="tag_100_not" href="#tag_100_box"  style="width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;display:block;"></a>100</th`>
```

The div is not disappearing.

I tried, onStart and onComplete, none work.

Comment: use .hide() instead of CSS for making stuff go away

Comment: No, I need that display none for an if. It doesnt work I already tried. Hide or .css it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Did you try removing the `display:block` from your markup? That is the wrong type of "display" to use for a table cell anyway.

Comment: I realize you have display block on the anchor tag, but does it actually have a width and height to it? When it's empty, it wont take up any space, and therefore, you won't notice it disappearing. When you initialize the fancybox, check using firebug if the anchor tag has display:none on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if it works for one rule, but as far as i know, the css method always accepts a hash

```
$('#tag_100_not').css({'display':'none'})
```

Though you can always save typing and just use the hide function:

```
$('#tag_100_not').hide()
```